# Coffee options for those with a weak stomach?

Tags: digestion

My stomach doesn't take coffee kindly for some reason, but I do like the taste and smell of it.

Are there any coffee types out there for those with a similar issue?

Answer (score 11):

Preparation method will have a big factor in extraction, acidity (such as in @Patrick's answer) among them.  The method used (temperature, time, technique, filtering method) will have a big impact on what comes out in the cup. [Astringency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astringent) and [bitterness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste#Bitterness) might also be factors that have physical effects for you; see [this article](http://www.coffeeresearch.org/science/bittermain.htm) for a discussion of the differences between the two, causes, and related factors.

**Try cold brew.** Cold brew coffee will have lower acidity, and might be a good option for you; [here's an article](http://www.specialty-coffee-advisor.com/coffee-brewing.html) that discusses different preparation methods, but in the cold-brew section it has an anecdote of someone with similar "stomach".  Here's [another on cold-brew and acidity](http://www.kickinghorsecoffee.com/en/blog/how-make-cold-brew-coffee). See also the [cold-brew](/questions/tagged/cold-brew) tag.

**Paper filtering** seems to remove some acids, but it's not clear whether these are the type that might argue with your stomach. For example, [The AeroPress FAQ](http://aerobie.com/Products/Details/AeroPressFAQ.htm) claims that their paper filter creates lower acidity brew, but I can't immediately find a better, proper reference.

**Try some antacid.** If you're experiencing heartburn, try a calcium-based antacid before and/or after drinking the coffee, and see if that changes things. (Disclaim: This isn't medical advice, don't take it if you shouldn't, talk to a doctor about meds, etc.).

**Science!** If you're into thicker scientific reading, here's [a paper on extraction methods and outcomes](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/125/art%253A10.1007%252Fs00217-013-1917-x.pdf?auth66=1423742173_f2bd9090ce696bb06eb8b37334874b92&ext=.pdf), if you're into that sort of thing. It discusses various aspects of acids and acidity. It looks pretty dense.

Comment: Plus one for going into so much detail. Good answer!

Answer (score 7):

I suggest looking for coffee types with lower acidity.

Dark roasts *generally* have lower acidity. I do know that **Nabob** has an acidity rating right on it's packaging. Some coffee shops will also be able to tell you how acidic their coffee is.

All coffee reacts in the stomach to create acid though. If a low-acid coffee doesn't do the trick for you, then you might just not be able to drink coffee.

Caffeine can also cause GI sensitivity. You may try a decaf, however these can tend to be more acidic than normal coffees.

Comment: There are other elements for a upset stomach. It can cause gas and stomachaches due to the fact it goes inside the small intestine too fast and other reasons. You should research a little more to clarify your answer.

Comment: @PythonMaster Yes but looking for a lower acidity coffee is about the only variable you can change. If you think you can prepare a better answer then by all means, go ahead.

Comment: +1 for acidity being a big factor. Here's [a table of coffee acidities](http://www.highlandcoffeesbr.com/coffeeprofileschart.php) that shows some regional trends in acidity.

Comment: It could actually be the caffeine as well, many people's stomachs are more sensitive to caffeine.  In that case, decaf may be an option.

Comment: @ChrisinAK Added that to the post. Thanks!